# Expectation of product of matrix from iid gaussian

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices, statistics, expected-value

I have a matrix X which is of size $(5,25)$ and the elements of the matrix are drawn from the standard normal distribution.

I need to derive $\mathbb E(X'X)$ i.e. the expectation of the product of $X$ times of itself.

Can you all please help me out. Thanks!

Comment: If you look at the $(i,j)$-entry of the matrix, it is $(X'X)_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^5 X_{ik}X_{kj}$. Can you compute this expectation, using the independence of the $X_{\ell k}$'s, for say the cases $i\neq j$  (and the case $i=j$ separately)?

Comment: You can use that $\mathbb E\left( X'X\right)=Var(X)-\mu\cdot \mu ^T$

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: @user755315 You´re welcome.